# constructor x in class x cannot be applied to given types. Between superclass and subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

The other questions I have seen are about intentionally referencing a superclass constructor method and failing. I am not referencing a constructor yet; just trying to extend a class.

I am creating the class Square.java, which extends Rectangle.java.

Square.java is the subclass of Rectangle.java.

Interface.java

-Abstract.java - abstract class Abstract implements Interface.java

--Rectangle.java - public class Rectangle extends Abstract

---Square.java - public class Square extends Rectangle.

When compiling Square.java, I received the error message.

```
Square.java:3: error: constructor Rectangle in class Rectangle cannot be applied to given types;
public class Square extends Rectangle {
       ^
  required: String,String,String,double,double
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

The content of Square.java is

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
       //no code is in the body

        }
```

The constructor method of rectangle is:

```
public Rectangle (String t,String n, String c, double w, double h ){
width = w;
height = h;
color = c;
name = n;
type = t;
    };
```

I want to create Square.java. Within this file, I would like to modify the Rectangle constructor method. But for right now, I just want the file to compile.

I have tried

- Copying the Rectangle constructor method into Square.java. That resulted in the same error message.
- Copying in the Rectangle constructor method and changing the name of the constructor method to Square. This resulted in the same error message.
- Commenting out the Rectangle constructor method within Rectangle.java. Square.java compiled without a problem. But... I need the Rectangle constructor in Rectangle.java.
- Creating a new Square constructor method and ran into more errors. Eventually, I want the Square constructor method to be a modified Rectangle constructor method.

From my understanding, constructor methods are not passed on to subclasses. I have not written code to intentionally reference the Rectangle constructor.

I am getting the feeling that the compiler is interpreting "... extends Rectangle { " as an attempt to reference the constructor instead of the class. I have run out of ideas on how to resolve this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All classes **must** contain at least one constructor. They cannot be compiled without having one.
2. All constructors **must** begin with a `super()` call of some sort (invoking a constructor in the parent class), unless they start with a `this()` call (redirect to another constructor).
3. ... However, if you fail to add a `super()` call, the compiler will simply assume you meant to and acts as if you wrote `super();` at the top of it.
4. ... However, if you fail to add a constructor, the compiler will simply assume you meant to write one, and acts as if you wrote: `public MyClassName() { super(); }`.

With these facts in mind, `super()` is not going to work in your case, because `Rectangle` does not have a no-args constructor.

All you need:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
  public Square(String t, String n, String c, double w) {
    super(t, n, c, w, w);
  }
}
```

This means Square has 1 constructor, taking 't', 'n', and 'c', whatever those are, as well as a single double indicating the length of any edge. (NB: This is **bad code style**, parameters should have clear names, *especially* if the type of the parameter isn't particularly enlightening. 'String c' means nothing. `Color c` - you can get away with that)

It then calls the Rectangle constructor, passing that 'edge length' value for *both* the width and height dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved with the help of this question. [Similar content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319817/how-to-inherit-constructor-from-super-class-to-sub-class#:%7E:text=Constructors%20are%20not%20inherited%2C%20you,matching%20constructor%20in%20the%20superclass.)

I create another constructor with super(), this resolved the error.

```
public Square (String t,String n, String c, double w, double h ){
            super(t,n,c,w,h);
    };
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense - it would let you make a square instance that isn't a square, i.e. - an 'object with invalid state': What if I call new Square(t, n, c, 10, 20);?

Comment: You're correct. The constructor isn't finished yet I still need to modify it to ensure the width and height are the same